# How to use function print value in tkinter label.config(text="printed value")

Tags: python, tkinter

I require help to use the function output to be used in a label.
I have tried `lbl.config(text=row.empid, row.joineddate)` and `lbl.config(text=print(row.empid, row.joineddate))` and none of them is working.

The function is:

```
def sqlstatement():
    con = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};server=localhost;database=employee;uid=admin;pwd=pwd")
    cur = con.cursor()
    sql= '''SELECT empid,joineddate from employee where empid= ?'''
    param_values=['11001']
    cur.execute(sql)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
            print(row.empid, row.joineddate)
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What does it do and do you get an error or is it different from what you expect? Also no one can run the code you posted since it selects information from your database (and is incomplete). We can't even see what's in `row.empid` and `row.joineddate`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the text of the label to be the concatenation of `row.empid` and `row.joineddate`, then neither of your current approaches work. The first one doesn't understand that you're trying to pass both empid and joineddate to the `text` argument. It thinks that joineddate is a separate argument. The second one simply prints empid and joineddate to stdout and sends the return value of `print` to the label. `print` always returns None, so that won't update the label properly either.

You should compose a single string, and pass that to the `text` argument instead. Try:

```
bl.config(text="{} {}".format(row.empid, row.joineddate))
```

Or, if your Python version supports f strings,

```
bl.config(text=f"{row.empid} {row.joineddate}")
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for the help. I have updated this as a string and it is now working fine. Appreciate your help.